# Variable assignment issues, how to interpret

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm having trouble understanding what's happening in this code:

```vb
Lock.Value = reader("Some_SQL_Value_Here") > approval
```

What's really confusing me is the greater than sign.

Does the Lock.Value get assigned the greater value?

does something else happen?

Comment: What if you "dumbed" the example down and used constant values for the variables: `Lock.Value = 1 > 2`. What would the value be for `Lock.Value` you think? If it is still not clear what do you think would be evaluated first?

Comment: In general this is a great opportunity to test and observe.  Write a small example which does nothing but what you're looking to observe and output the result.  What is that result?  Make use of a debugger to step through the code line by line as it executes and observe the values being set.  What is the value?  "What does this code do" can almost *always* be answered by executing the code and observing the result.

Comment: I realized my mistake, I didn't even think about Booleans. *Due to outside forces, I cannot debug or run. Just observe and make assumptions on the data coming through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part:

```
reader("Some_SQL_Value_Here") > approval
```

is a `Boolean` expression. It evaluates to either `True` or `False`. It is that `Boolean` value that is assigned to the property.  It's akin to this:

```
Lock.Value = reader("Some_SQL_Value_Here") + approval
```

Would you be confused by an expression containing an operator evaluating to a value and that value being assigned in this case? I would think not. Your original code is basically the same, except a magnitude comparison evaluates to a `Boolean` where an addition evaluates to a number.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm feeling pretty stupid now. I should have realized that. Thank you though, the rest make more sense now!